# How to see live status changes of a systemctl service?

Tags: monitoring, tmux

I have a service that is run via systemctl and I want to see its live status of changes when things change. I have a tmux window open for it and just wanted to get a running account when things change. Or is this no the best way to do it? Mainly I want it posted to the screen when this fail or something happens.

Comment: There's a better answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1042175/how-do-i-get-systemctl-to-print-in-color-when-being-interacted-with-from-a-non-t

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the service you want to monitor is `xyz.service` you could do this, in a terminal window:

```
journalctl --follow -u xyz.service
```

Comment: `-u` stands for unit, so:
`journalctl --follow --unit=xyz.service`